# statement to find at least a year with register users > 1

Tags: mysql

i need to find find the years for which have at least 2 users register.

the table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rotef`.`users` (
  `id` INT(11) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `year` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and the data

```
INSERT INTO `rotef`.`users` (`id`, `name`,`year`) VALUES (1,"john", 2016);
INSERT INTO `rotef`.`users` (`id`, `name`,`year`) VALUES (2,"jim", 2016);
INSERT INTO `rotef`.`users` (`id`, `name`,`year`) VALUES (3,"eric", 2014);
INSERT INTO `rotef`.`users` (`id`, `name`,`year`) VALUES (4,"jesi", 2012);
INSERT INTO `rotef`.`users` (`id`, `name`,`year`) VALUES (5,"jef", 2011);
```

the statement based on the above data must return 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) `year`, and use a [`HAVING`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause to further limit only the grups where the count or rows (`count(*)`) is greater than 1:

```
SELECT
    year
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    year
HAVING
    count(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    year ;
```

You get:

```
| year |
|------|
| 2016 |
```

You can check it at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7585d/1/0)